# Finally on rxjs sequence gets executed on first error

Tags: javascript, sequence, rxjs, observable

I try to execute a finally statement on a Observable - sequence of http-calls.

The finally method gets executed on the first error, and not when the complete sequenze is finished.

```
deleteLeistungsTarife(
    leistungsTarife: Shopeinstellungen.LeistungsTarif[],
    leistungstarifGeloeschtCallback: (leistungsTarif: Shopeinstellungen.LeistungsTarif) => any) {
    let observerListe: Observable<number>[] = [];
    leistungsTarife.forEach((lt) => observerListe.push(
        this.http.delete(this._leistungenUrl + '/DeleteLeistungsTarif/' + lt.tarifLeistungId)
            .map(res => leistungstarifGeloeschtCallback(lt))
            .catch(this.handleError)                
    ));
    return Observable.forkJoin(observerListe).finally(()=>console.log("finally"));
}
```

the call for this method looks like this:

```
    this._leistungenService.deleteLeistungsTarife(
        zuLoeschendeTarife, leistungsTarif => {
            console.log("gespeichert: ", leistungsTarif)
        }
    ).subscribe(
        (r) => console.log("liste result:", r),
        (e) => console.log("liste error:", e),
        () => console.log("complete")
    )
```

Even there is no error, the finally and complete console-logs get hit after the first observable is finished :/

Is there an alternative function for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected and documented behavior of the `finally` function. Check the [documentation](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/finally.md).

> Invokes a specified action after the source observable sequence terminates gracefully or exceptionally.

Also by Rxjs grammar, there can only be one error emitted by an observable, which implies [completion when an error occurs](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/designguidelines/readme.md):

> Messages sent to instances of the Observer object follow the following grammar: onNext* (onCompleted | onError)?
>
> This grammar allows observable sequences to send any amount (0 or more) of onNext messages to the subscribed observer instance, optionally followed by a single success (onCompleted) or failure (onError) message.
>
> The single message indicating that an observable sequence has finished ensures that consumers of the observable sequence can deterministically establish that it is safe to perform cleanup operations.
>
> A single failure further ensures that abort semantics can be maintained for operators that work on multiple observable sequences.

To call a function only when completion of the observable, you can use two main techniques :

- [`doOnCompleted`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/dooncompleted.md)
- use [`materialize`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/materialize.md) to treat `onNext`, `onError`, and `onCompleted` as regular values (and `dematerialize` to get the normal behavior back).

In your particular case however, I believe the approach is to:

- `catch` the errors, and replace the error by an error code (i.e. don't throw or forcefully terminates the stream, return a value which encapsulates the error). That way the source completes normally and the `forkJoin` too.

I don't see the code for your handler, but I suppose it probably terminates its observable? If that's the case you could return an error code, and analyze the values of all the calls once they finish with the `resultSelector` parameter of [`forkJoin`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/forkjoin.md#arguments).